# Using a boolean function in scheme

Tags: function, scheme, boolean

I want to use "member" function like "eq", "null" etc. However, I do not know how can I fix it?

```
(define (member atm lst)
    (cond
        ((null? lst) #F)
        ((eq? atm (car lst)) #T)
        (else (member atm (cdr lst)))
    )
)
```

and where I used;

```
(define (duplicate-entries lst)
    (cond
        ((null? lst) #F)
        ((member? (car lst) (cdr lst))) #T)
        (else duplicate-entries (cdr lst))
    )
)
```

`member?` does not work, how can i fix it?

Comment: Well, it is just because `member?` ist an unbound variable, you did not define it! You defined `member`. By the way, you are essentially talking about the `memq`-function wich is part of any R5RS compliant implementation. Besides, there are some other flaws: `duplicate-entries` misses a bracket and its intention is not quite clear.

Comment: Please indent the code according to the Scheme convention - notice that closing parenthesis should be left in the same line, not in a different line like one does with braces in other languages. And the boolean values are written in lowercase: `#t, #f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `member` function whereas you are using `member?`. Define `member` as `member?` i.e `(define (member? atm lst) ... )`

Comment: This is right, but according to the semantics of scheme the question-mark is wrong, because the OP’s function does not necessarily return a boolean (see also my comment above and R5RS).

Comment: @LudwigMeier: I think the OP implementation of member has only boolean  return value.. isn't it?

Comment: I am sorry, you are right of course. While testing, I must have messed it up with the buildt-in `member`-function, which indeed returns no boolean. So my first comment was nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at each procedure in turn, first `member`. Be aware that there's already a standard [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._member%29%29) function in Scheme, so it's a bad idea to define a new procedure with the same name. Here's what the existing `member` procedure does:

> `member` locates the first element of lst that is `equal?` to `v`. If such an element exists, the tail of lst starting with that element is returned. Otherwise, the result is `#f`.

The above procedure uses `equal?` for testing and returns a value different to what you expect. Somewhat closer to the intended procedure, we have the standard [`memq`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._memq%29%29) function:

> `memq` like member, but finds an element using eq?.

But again, the returned value is not what you expect. I suggest you define your procedure like this, noticing that we're using `memq`, and according to the convention, the name ends with a `?` to indicate that this is a boolean procedure:

```
(define (member? atm lst)
  (if (memq atm lst) #t #f))
```

Now let's look at `duplicate-entries`. There are a couple of parenthesis problems (correctly indenting the code would have shown this), and there's a problem with the name of the membership procedure (your procedure is called `member` but you're invoking it as `member?`). You either use the `member?` we just defined above, or use `memq`, both approaches will work fine in this case, because `memq` will return a non-false value if the element was found, and that will make the condition true:

```
(define (duplicate-entries lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((member? (car lst) (cdr lst)) #t)
        (else (duplicate-entries (cdr lst)))))
```

Or this, which is the recommended way - there's no need to reinvent the wheel if an existing procedure does what you need:

```
(define (duplicate-entries lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((memq (car lst) (cdr lst)) #t)
        (else (duplicate-entries (cdr lst)))))
```